# Find a representation of $(M_n(\mathbb C),tr_n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

> Find a unital *-algebra homomorphism $\Phi$ from $M_n(\mathbb C)$ to the set of bounded linear operators on $\mathbb C^{n^2}$ an a unit vector $\xi\in \mathbb C^{n^2}$ such that $tr_n(A)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i A_{ii}=\langle \Phi(A)\xi,\xi\rangle$ for all $A\in M_n(\mathbb C)$.

Since the bounded linear operator on $\mathbb C^{n^2}$ can be represented in the standard basis as matrix in $M_{n^2}(\mathbb C)$, we have to find for every $A\in M_{n}(\mathbb C)$ some $X\in M_{n^2}(\mathbb C)$ such that $tr_n(A)=\sum_{i,j}X_ {ij}\xi_i\xi_j$. The hard part is we must have $\Phi(AB)=\Phi(A)\Phi(B)$, so $X$ cannot be diagonal.

Any hints on how to find a $\Phi$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand which inner product you are endowing $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$ with, but I can at least suggest an idea for a natural homomorphism $\phi$. If you identify $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$ with $\text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ as a vector space, then you could define the action : $$\phi(A)\xi = A \xi. $$ This defines a linear map $\phi(A) :  \text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C}) \to \text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$, and the assignment $A \mapsto \phi(A)$ is clearly an algebra homomorphism with $\phi(I_n) = \text{id}_{\text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})}$.

Now, if you endow $\text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ with the following inner product : $$ \langle \xi_1, \xi_2 \rangle = \text{Tr}(\xi_2^*\xi_1) , $$ then you can check that $\phi$ is further a $*$-algebra homomorphism. Indeed, you can compute : $$ \langle \phi(A)\xi_1,\xi_2 \rangle = \text{Tr}(\xi_2^* A \xi_1 ) = \text{Tr}((A^*\xi_2)^* \xi_1) = \langle \xi_1,\phi(A^*)\xi_2 \rangle , $$ for all $\xi_1,\xi_2 \in \text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$. This proves that $\phi(A^*) = \phi(A)^*$.

Finally, the unit vector $\xi = I_n$ has the desired property that : $$ \langle \phi(A)\xi,\xi \rangle = \text{Tr}(\xi^* A \xi) = \text{Tr}(A) . $$ Actually, it seems that any $\xi \in \text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $\xi^* \xi = I_n$ (ie. any unitary matrix) has this property, but the identity matrix is certainly the easiest choice here.

I hope this helps !